# Conteúdo oculto é ruim para acessibilidade?

Tags: jquery, html, acessibilidade

Tenho uma tabela com três colunas, uma para "Espécie", uma para "Quantidade" e uma para opções. O campo quantidade pode ser alterado quando for clicado no botão alterar, sendo o botão alterar ocultado para aparecer o botão salvar.

```
<table class="table">
    ....
    <tr>
       <td>Espécie 1 </td>
       <td>
          <span id="sQtde_1">10 </span>
          <input type="text" id="txtQtde_1" value"10" class="form-control hide">
       </td>
       <td>
         <button type="button" value="1" class="btn">Alterar</button>
         <button type="button" id="btnSalvar_1" value="1" class="btn hide">Salvar</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function alterar(botao) {
      var n = $(botao).val();
      $("#txtQtde_" + n).toggleClass('hide');
      $("#sQtde_" + n).toggleClass('hide');
      $("#btnSalvar_" + n).toggleClass('hide');
      $(button).toggleClass('hide');
    }
</script>
```

Esse tipo de prática de ocultar/mostrar elementos com CSS pode ser ruim no que diz a respeito a acessibilidade por exemplo pra usuários cegos?

Answer (score 0):

Elementos ocultos (`style="display:none;"` e `<input type="hidden">`) não são lidos pelos leitores de tela como NVDA e JAWS, os leitores de tela ignoram esses tipos de elementos.